# Can jQuery reset parent height after ajax load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Haven't had much luck with the call back function when trying to reset the height of the parent container.

Events:

1. user clicks on `.boxyComments a`
2. `.showComments`  takes the `load` and brings in content. the `relative` css attribute changes it's height
3. `.boxy` resizes with the added height values of it's inner elements `.articleImageThumb`, `.initialPostLoad` and the changed height value of `.showComments`

Step 3 is not resizing. Wrapped with a `(window).load` still doesn't change the `height` value until after the entire function has completed, resulting in no change to the height of the parent `.boxy`.

SO `FRUSTRATING`....

Example below:

```
$(".boxyComments a").click(function (event) {

        var postHeight = $(this).closest('.boxy').find('.articleImageThumb').height();
        var excHeight = $(this).closest('.boxy').find('.initialPostLoad').height();
        var bComments = $(this).closest(".showComments").height();

        event.preventDefault();
        var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $(this).closest(".boxyComments").find(".showComments")
        .load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajax-fold/",{id: post_id}, function() {
            console.log(excHeight)
            $(document).ready().closest('.boxy').animate({height:  postHeight + excHeight}, 500);
        });
});
```

semipseudo output:

```
<div class="boxy">

<div class="articleImageThumb">
<a href="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", true)) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", true);
    else the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'original'); ?>
</a>
</div>

<div class="boxyComments">
<a href="<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", true)) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "url", true); else the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>" >Open Comments</a>
<div class="showComments"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

console.log output only gives the `height()` value before the `load()` finishes.

Is there a way to reset that after the `load`?

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Your code is confusing. Step by step, please.

Comment: @silkfire events added above

Comment: Is it because some elements are hidden and height can't be calculated properly?

Comment: @silkfire the `showComments` div isn't hidden, but it is empty without any CSS values attributed. Would that affect anything?

Comment: Why doesn't it have CSS already applied?

Comment: @silkfire I was hoping that would be applied with the jQuery `load` attributing some size. Am I wrong? My brain wants to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call:

```
 excHeight = $(document).ready().closest('.boxy').find('.showComments').height();
```

After the load/load complete, so you will end up with something like:

```
.load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajax-fold/",{id: post_id}, function() {
        excHeight =  $(document).ready().closest('.boxy').find('.showComments').height();
        console.log(excHeight)
        $(document).ready().closest('.boxy').animate({height:  postHeight + excHeight}, 500);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! Tried it, but `excHeight` is still giving the value prior to the `load`. Is there a way to reset that value after the `load`?

Comment: Im guessing you need ".showComments" height so i've updated the execHeight

Comment: You've definitely got a point. That's the div that should be expanded after all. The method works but isn't resizing the `.boxy` parent container. Console.log after this `load` still gives the wrong value. Is there a way to refresh the value manually?

Comment: Yes you can, figure out the size then: $(document).ready().closest('.boxy').css('height', varnameofheight) 
or
$(document).ready().closest('.boxy').height(varnameofheight)

Comment: @canacast when you run the line $(document).ready().closest('.boxy').find('.showComments').height(); what response do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You're jquery seems to be wrong.

Right off the bat, this code will error out with null

```
var excHeight = $(this).closest('.boxy').find('.initialPostLoad').height();
```

the .boxy div doesn't have a child with the class .initialPostLoad

Then you try to get the height for .showcomments using `.closest()`.

```
.closest()
```

goes up the DOM structure to find a match, but what you're looking for is a sibling.

Try this instead

```
var bComments = $(this).siblings(".showComments").height();
```